# Protocol for secure communication over HTTP

Tags: encryption, cryptography, protocols

Inspired by this hot question: [Is there any reason to block HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103540/is-there-any-reason-to-block-https)

Is there a way to setup an own server and encrypt all normal requests in  the request body?

So for an outside person it would look like filling out a weird form with random data and getting random data back, but in reality it would be the same as the https traffic, or similarly encrypted?

Theoretically this should work, but does such a protocol exist? https over http?

Answer (score 11):

You ask for tunneling a protocol (like HTTPS) through plain HTTP. And yes, there is at least [httptunnel](http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/) which does this. From the descrition:

> HTTPTunnel is a tunneling software that can tunnel network connections through restrictive HTTP proxies over pure HTTP "GET" and "POST" requests.

But note that if you work in an environment where use of HTTPS is restricted for security or productivity reasons, using such a tool to bypass the block is usually a violation of the policy. And usage of the tool can be detected because it shows abnormal traffic patterns.

Answer (score -1):

An encrypted [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) does exactly that.

Comment: A VPN usually does not transmit it's data through HTTP requests.